# How to install Qt5 with switchable Kits in QtCreator using offline installers?

Tags: qt, qt5, qt-creator

Having some issues with the online installers, I would like to use the offline installers to create an installation with multiple Kits and versions. I would like to be able to switch between MinGW, Visual Studio and mobile targets just by switching between the Kits, and I would like to have the latest two Qt versions (5.4 and 5.5) available for choosing.

However, there are some issues with this:

- The offline installers are only available with a single Kit. Installing the same version twice with different Kits to the same directory seems to mix up Qt Creator's available Kits, and the installation seems to replace the previous one in Windows' list of installed software.
- Every single setup comes with its own Qt creator instance, and only there the Kits are available as desired. So when installing in seperate directories, a lot of duplicate stuff is installed.
- I tried copying together kits from a few installations, but running a big installation, copying part of it and then patching the kit with the installer again seems to be a bit weird ...

Isn't there an easier way to get a consistent installation on Windows with the offline installers?

Comment: You should install Qt Creator separately (there is a Qt Creator-only download I think), then use Tools->Options->Build&Run->Kits->Add to add all the kits manually, after you download them. That's how did it.

Comment: Or use one of the bundled qt creators and configure the Qt’s from the other  installations under “Qt versions”, by selecting the respective qmake.exe’s.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Qt Creator's kits and whatever Qt versions you install are separate matters. It's up to you to set up as many kits as you desire. The installers may add a default kit to the creator they bundle, but that's just for convenience. You're free, nah, you have to set things up yourself per your requirements.

Comment: This is a really sad state of affairs.  You shouldn't have to jump through ridiculous hoops like this just because you want to build both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of your Hello World program while retaining offline installations.  (It's not like the online installer will work forever...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I believe this issue is not as big as I thought: Even the multiple Qt Creator installations that come with every offline installer do not create any bigger conflicts. The only thing that might happen with these: When starting different versions of Creator after each other, one might see conflicts with the settings files of QtCreator which are always stored in `%APPDATA%/QtProject`: Using an older version can corrupt the newer one.

That said, I believe the simplest way to work with different Qt Versions is to use a new installation folder for every Qt version, and to use a separate installation of QtCreator. Then one of course has to set up debuggers, Qt Versions and Kits manually for each new installation. The benefit of this is that one can also simply remove any version one doesn't need anymore - without risking to remove the used Qt Creator.

Qt creator automatically seems to detect and select appropriate help files + examples from the installed Qt versions.

Compared to using the online installer, the installation needs more space for the multiple Qt Creators, however installations are really separate from each other, so there is no risk in messing up anything by using the online installers again when a new version comes: the online installer only gives the latest two major versions with their latest minor version, and when changing from one minor version to another, one might want to compare results between these.